# SQL Server - FOR JSON PATH

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, for-json

I know I need to use FOR JSON to make this work, I just unsure of how to do groups by a certain column for this.

I have the following dataset:

```
property confirmation exemptions                                taxReasonId                 taxId
0145     29SW8TW9F    2020-05-09: ["occupancy tax","room tax"]  5e61836ed0687c000143d77e    OTA Prepaid
0145     2QWKNZM8F    2020-08-07: ["occupancy tax","room tax"]  5e61836ed0687c000143d77e    OTA Prepaid
0145     2QWKNZM8F    2020-08-08: ["occupancy tax","room tax"]  5e61836ed0687c000143d77e    OTA Prepaid
0145     3BM6SV9C3    2020-06-25: ["occupancy tax","room tax"]  5e61836ed0687c000143d77e    OTA Prepaid
0145     3BM6SV9C3    2020-06-26: ["occupancy tax","room tax"]  5e61836ed0687c000143d77e    OTA Prepaid
0145     3BM6SV9C3    2020-06-27: ["occupancy tax","room tax"]  5e61836ed0687c000143d77e    OTA Prepaid
0145     3BM6SV9C3    2020-06-28: ["occupancy tax","room tax"]  5e61836ed0687c000143d77e    OTA Prepaid
0145     3BM6SV9C3    2020-06-29: ["occupancy tax","room tax"]  5e61836ed0687c000143d77e    OTA Prepaid    
0145     3BM6SV9C3    2020-06-30: ["occupancy tax","room tax"]  5e61836ed0687c000143d77e    OTA Prepaid
0145     3BM6SV9C3    2020-07-01: ["occupancy tax","room tax"]  5e61836ed0687c000143d77e    OTA Prepaid
0145     3BM6SV9C3    2020-07-02: ["occupancy tax","room tax"]  5e61836ed0687c000143d77e    OTA Prepaid
0145     3BM6SV9C3    2020-07-03: ["occupancy tax","room tax"]  5e61836ed0687c000143d77e    OTA Prepaid
0145     3BM6SV9C3    2020-07-04: ["occupancy tax","room tax"]  5e61836ed0687c000143d77e    OTA Prepaid
0145     3FY4HQ7RB    2020-05-13: ["occupancy tax","room tax"]  5e61836ed0687c000143d77e    OTA Prepaid
0145     3FY4HQ7RB    2020-05-14: ["occupancy tax","room tax"]  5e61836ed0687c000143d77e    OTA Prepaid
0145     3FY4HQ7RB    2020-05-15: ["occupancy tax","room tax"]  5e61836ed0687c000143d77e    OTA Prepaid
0145     3FY4HQ7RB    2020-05-16: ["occupancy tax","room tax"]  5e61836ed0687c000143d77e    OTA Prepaid
0145     3FY4HQ7RB    2020-05-17: ["occupancy tax","room tax"]  5e61836ed0687c000143d77e    OTA Prepaid
0145     3FY4HQ7RB    2020-05-18: ["occupancy tax","room tax"]  5e61836ed0687c000143d77e    OTA Prepaid
0145     3FY4HQ7RB    2020-05-19: ["occupancy tax","room tax"]  5e61836ed0687c000143d77e    OTA Prepaid
0145     3FY4HQ7RB    2020-05-20: ["occupancy tax","room tax"]  5e61836ed0687c000143d77e    OTA Prepaid
0145     3FY4HQ7RB    2020-05-21: ["occupancy tax","room tax"]  5e61836ed0687c000143d77e    OTA Prepaid
0145     3FY4HQ7RB    2020-05-22: ["occupancy tax","room tax"]  5e61836ed0687c000143d77e    OTA Prepaid
0145     3FY4HQ7RB    2020-05-23: ["occupancy tax","room tax"]  5e61836ed0687c000143d77e    OTA Prepaid
0145     3FY4HQ7RB    2020-05-24: ["occupancy tax","room tax"]  5e61836ed0687c000143d77e    OTA Prepaid
0145     3FY4HQ7RB    2020-05-25: ["occupancy tax","room tax"]  5e61836ed0687c000143d77e    OTA Prepaid
0145     3FY4HQ7RB    2020-05-26: ["occupancy tax","room tax"]  5e61836ed0687c000143d77e    OTA Prepaid
```

I need to turn each group of "confirmation" into a JSON payload, preferably with an identifier column of "confirmation":

```
{
    "taxId": "OTAPrepaid",
    "taxReasonId": "5e61836ed0687c000143d77e",
    "exemptions":
    {
        "2020-08-07": ["occupancy tax", "room tax"],
        "2020-08-08": ["occupancy tax", "room tax"]
    }
}
```

This is the query I am using to get my dataset:

```
SELECT  res.property, res.confirmationId, CAST(date AS VARCHAR(12)) + ': ' + tax.taxClass AS exemptions, id AS taxReasonId, tax.reasonName AS taxId
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  property, date, confirmationId
            FROM dbo.tb_rguest_reservation_records
                WHERE CAST(property AS INT) IN
                (
                    50,66,74,98,105,149,            --Kentucky, Room Tax Exempt
                    132,                            --South Carolina, Room and Occupancy Tax Exempt
                    11,160,165,167,             --Colorado, Room Tax Exempt
                    19,46,87,88,145,169,191,        --Indiana, Room and Occupancy Tax Exempt
                    116,142,162                 --New Mexico, Room Tax Exempt
                )
                AND ratePlanId IN ('NOPTS','ADVOTC','ADVPLA','ADVHT','OTAPLA','OTAPAO','OTAHT','OTAHOT')
                AND arrivalDate >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
                AND property = '0145'
    ) res
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT property, reasonName, id, taxClass
            FROM dbo.tb_rguest_tax_exempt_reasons
                WHERE reasonName = 'OTA Prepaid'

    ) tax
        ON res.property = tax.property
            FOR JSON PATH
```

When I run the FOR JSON PATH it gives me the following, which is not what I am looking for exactly.

```
[
    {
        "property": "0145",
        "confirmationId": "74XD3NMWF",
        "exemptions": "2020-03-06: [\"occupancy tax\",\"room tax\"]",
        "taxReasonId": "5e61836ed0687c000143d77e",
        "taxId": "OTA Prepaid"
    },
    {
        "property": "0145",
        "confirmationId": "T6JYFMT6P",
        "exemptions": "2020-03-06: [\"occupancy tax\",\"room tax\"]",
        "taxReasonId": "5e61836ed0687c000143d77e",
        "taxId": "OTA Prepaid"
    },
    {
        "property": "0145",
        "confirmationId": "92DR3M7DB",
        "exemptions": "2020-03-11: [\"occupancy tax\",\"room tax\"]",
        "taxReasonId": "5e61836ed0687c000143d77e",
        "taxId": "OTA Prepaid"
    },
```

etc...

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: I haven't tried much other than just using FOR JSON PATH which I have used very little in the past. I am just unsure of how to make the dates work. I will add the query above.

Comment: Please do show us your attempt(s) on the question. It really helps is help you.

Comment: Just added the query I am using for the dataset and the response (limited). I am just unsure how to group anything with FOR JSON PATH. I have done quite a bit of JSON Parsing, but not JSON creation.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: SQL Server 2016, sorry for the delayed response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is as ugly of logic as it comes to me, but it works...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.##temp', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##temp;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.##temp2', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##temp2;

DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @jsonValue AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @dateChange DATE

DECLARE @property VARCHAR(4)
    SET @property = '0145'

DECLARE @confirmation VARCHAR(12)
    SET @confirmation = 'C3Q28J82B'

DECLARE @taxClass VARCHAR(100)
    SET @taxClass =
(
    SELECT taxClass
        FROM dbo.tb_rguest_tax_exempt_reasons
            WHERE property = @property
            AND reasonName = 'OTA Prepaid'
)

DECLARE @dateColumns AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @dateColumns =
    STUFF(
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(date)
            FROM dbo.tb_rguest_reservation_records
                WHERE confirmationId = @confirmation
                AND property = @property
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

DECLARE @dateCount INT
    SET @dateCount =
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM dbo.tb_rguest_reservation_records
            WHERE confirmationId = @confirmation
            AND property = @property
)

DECLARE @dateCounter INT
    SET @dateCounter = 1

SET @query =  
'SELECT *
    INTO ##temp
    FROM
    (
        SELECT res.confirmationId, tax.reasonName AS taxId, tax.id AS taxReasonId, 
               res.date, JSON_QUERY(tax.taxClass) AS taxClass
            FROM dbo.tb_rguest_reservation_records res
            LEFT JOIN dbo.tb_rguest_tax_exempt_reasons tax
                ON res.property = tax.property
                    WHERE res.confirmationId = ' + '''' + @confirmation + '''' + '
    ) AS res
    PIVOT
    (
        MIN(res.taxClass)
            FOR [date] IN ('+ @dateColumns +')
    ) AS pvt'

EXEC (@query)

SET @query =
'DECLARE @jsonValue VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @jsonValue =
    (
        SELECT  taxId,
                taxreasonId,
                ' +
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                            @dateColumns, '[', 'JSON_QUERY(['
                                ), ']', '])'
                        ), ',', ' AS [exemptions.1], ') + ' AS [exemptions.2]' + '
            FROM ##temp
                FOR JSON PATH
    )

SELECT @jsonValue AS jsonValue
    INTO ##temp2'

EXEC (@query)

SET @jsonValue =
(
    SELECT jsonValue
        FROM ##temp2
)

WHILE @dateCounter <= @dateCount
BEGIN

SET @dateChange =
(
    SELECT date
        FROM
        (
            SELECT property, confirmationId, date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY date) AS rowNumber
                FROM dbo.tb_rguest_reservation_records
                    WHERE confirmationId = @confirmation
                    AND property = @property
        ) res
            WHERE rowNumber = @dateCounter
)

SET @jsonValue =REPLACE(@jsonValue, '"' + CAST(@dateCounter AS VARCHAR(12)) + '"', '"' + CAST(@dateChange AS VARCHAR(12)) + '"')

SET @dateCounter = @dateCounter + 1

END

SELECT @jsonValue
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an instance of SQL Server 2016 at hand, but on SQL Server 2017 this query seems to give the result you want:

```
SELECT confirmation,
       MAX(taxId)       as taxId,
       MAX(taxReasonId) as taxReasonId,
       JSON_QUERY('{' +
                  STRING_AGG('"' + SUBSTRING(exemptions, 1, 10) + '"' +
                             SUBSTRING(exemptions, 11, 100),
                             ', ') +
                  '}')  as exemptions
FROM tb_rguest_reservation_records t
GROUP BY confirmation FOR JSON PATH
```

[Here's](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1cfbb/72) a fiddle and below an example of the result:

```
[
    {
        "confirmation": "29SW8TW9F",
        "exemptions": {
            "2020-05-09": [
                "occupancy tax",
                "room tax"
            ]
        },
        "taxId": "OTA Prepaid",
        "taxReasonId": "5e61836ed0687c000143d77e"
    },
    {
        "confirmation": "2QWKNZM8F",
        "exemptions": {
            "2020-08-07": [
                "occupancy tax",
                "room tax"
            ],
            "2020-08-08": [
                "occupancy tax",
                "room tax"
            ]
        },
        "taxId": "OTA Prepaid",
        "taxReasonId": "5e61836ed0687c000143d77e"
    },
    ...
]
```

EDIT

Here's the same query w/o `STRING_AGG` for backward compatibility:

```
SELECT confirmation,
    MAX(taxId)       as taxId,
    MAX(taxReasonId) as taxReasonId,
    JSON_QUERY('{' + 
               STUFF((SELECT ',' + '"' + SUBSTRING(exemptions,1,10) + 
                             '"' + SUBSTRING(exemptions, 11, 100)
                      FROM tb_rguest_reservation_records t1
                      WHERE t1.confirmation = t2.confirmation
                      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
      + '}')         as exemptions
FROM tb_rguest_reservation_records t2
GROUP BY confirmation
FOR JSON PATH
```

Comment: This would be soooooo much easier if I had SQL 2017...

STRING_AGG isn't available until 17.